# How can I mock the CakeRquest Object When Testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp

I'm using cake 2.x and I'm trying to mock the CakeRequest object. Here's my attempt:

```
$AppUsers = $this->generate('AppUsers', array(
        'models' => array(
            'AppUser' => array('testIfValidates')
        ),
        'components' => array(
            'Auth',
            'Session',
            'Email' => array('send')
        )
    ));
 $request = $this->getMock('CakeRequest');
    $this->controller->request = $request;
    $this->controller->request->expects($this->once())
        ->method('is')
        ->with('ajax')
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));
 $this->testAction('/AppUsers/add');
```

And in my controller

```
 public function add() {
$this->request->is('ajax');
}
```

I get the error:
Expectation failed for method name is equal to  when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times. Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Comment: testAction already assigns that property - `$this->request` in the controller will point at a different object when the action is executed.

Comment: Ahh ok, is there any documentation on testing and not using $this->testAction

Comment: I forget the normal way to do it - you can just put what [CakePHP is looking for](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Network/CakeRequest.php#L106) in the environment so that it's considered an ajax request.